# One of Drupal Commerce shipping services abruptly disappears/rule gets deleted

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce, drupal-rules

I am not sure whether this a bug or not. I have one shipping method that includes two shipping services. One of the shipping services is available only if the ordered items include Arabic language books; in such a case the user is represented with two shipping options instead of one.

Apparently for no obvious reason, one the shipping services becomes broken and the rules component suddenly disappears.

I didn't create the rule myself, I found out that the rule "Collect rates: IPS" is created. Also, the rules components are created on the fly.

The shipping services I am referring to is called "kkkkkkk". Please find below some screenshots and my code for more info:

[image: Shipping Services]

```
function myips_commerce_shipping_method_info() {
    $shipping_methods = array();
    $shipping_methods['ippppps'] = array(
        'title' => t('IPS'),
        'description' => t('IPS commerce shipping'),
    );
    commerce_shipping_services_reset();
    //entity_defaults_rebuild();
    //rules_clear_cache(TRUE);
    return $shipping_methods;
}
function myips_commerce_shipping_service_info() {


    $contains_arabic=arabic_books_contained();
    $shipping_services = array();


    $shipping_services['ppppp'] = array(
        'title' => 'Express Mail - DHL',
        //'description' => 'Express Mail - DHL',
        'display_title' => t('Express Mail - DHL'),
        'shipping_method' => 'ippppps',
        'price_component' => 'shipping',
        'callbacks' => array(
            'rate' => 'commerce_ipppppls_service_rate_order',
        ),
    );


    if($contains_arabic=='true') {
        $shipping_services['kkkkkkk'] = array( //arbitrary name w/ 'service' in there
            'title' => 'kkkkkkk',  //title for the interface
           // 'description' => 'Lebanon Shipment option for books shipped from lebanon',
            'display_title' => t('Registered Mail'),
            'shipping_method' => 'ippppps',
            'price_component' => 'shipping',
            'callbacks' => array(
                'rate' => 'commerce_ipppppsssss_service_rate_order',
                ),
        );


    }
    return $shipping_services;
}

my shipping rule:

    { "commerce_shipping_method_ippppps" : {
    "LABEL" : "Collect rates: IPS",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_shipping" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_shipping_collect_rates" : [] },
    "DO" : [
    { "commerce_shipping_method_collect_rates" : {
    "shipping_method_name" : "ippppps",
    "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-order" ]
    }
    }
    ]
    }
    }
```

my shipping rule component for one of the shipping services, the second appears abruptly:

```
    { "commerce_shipping_service_ppppp" : {
"LABEL" : "Rate Express Mail - DHL",
"PLUGIN" : "rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_shipping" ],
"USES VARIABLES" : { "commerce_order" : { "type" : "commerce_order", "label" : "Order" } },
"DO" : [
{ "commerce_shipping_service_rate_order" : {
"shipping_service_name" : "ppppp",
"commerce_order" : [ "commerce-order" ]
}
}
]
}
}
```

Am I missing something, should I add something in my code, should any custom rules be created?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you do the update first?

Comment: Are you replacing a rule created by the module using import? I've discovered the hard way that when you import a rule using the importer to replace an existing rule it might get cleared (i.e. restored to the original) when CRON runs.